# Some emails are not being sent

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird for a few years (my email + domain are from Gandi), I have noticed that some of my "sent" emails are not arriving to their destinations, although they appear in the "Sent" items folder. I also tried to send 3 tests emails to my Gmail account and received only 2 of them.

I am very worried, since this is my business email and I assume some of my customers did not get my emails.

Appreciate any help,
Uri

Comment: that's hardly a unix question, have you check "spam" folder ?

Comment: I could not find Gmail spam, now I did thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Gmail thought it is spam...

That's why

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#authentication